# Passing parameter bindings to Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder, union-all

I currently have a SQL query which a fantastic stackoverflow member helped me with earlier today. At the moment it works absolutely fine and the way I want it to work.

The only problem is it's RAW SQL and I'd very much like to get this working with the Laravel Query Builder.

SORRY THIS IS AN EDIT - HERE IS THE ORIGINAL QUERY:

```
    $addresses = DB::select(
        DB::raw('
            (SELECT 
                "Company" AS object_type_name,
                companies.company_name AS object_name,
                addresses.*
            FROM 
                addresses
            INNER JOIN 
                companies 
            ON 
                addresses.object_id = companies.id
            WHERE 
                addresses.object_type = 2) 
            UNION ALL 
            (SELECT
                "Job" AS object_type_name,
                jobs.job_title AS object_name,
                addresses.*
            FROM 
                addresses
            INNER JOIN 
                jobs
            ON 
                addresses.object_id = jobs.id
            WHERE 
                addresses.object_type = 4)
        '));
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    $bindings = array(
        'soft_deleted' => 0,
        'user' => 1,
        'company' => 2,
        'candidate' => 3,
        'job' => 4,
    );

    $companies = DB::table('addresses')->select(
      'addresses.*',
      'companies.company_name as object_name'
    )->where('addresses.soft_deleted', '=', 0)->join('companies', function($join) use ($bindings){
        $join->on('addresses.object_id', '=', 'companies.id')
             ->where('addresses.object_type', '=', $bindings['company']);
    });

    $jobs = DB::table('addresses')->select(
      'addresses.*',
      'jobs.job_title as object_name'
    )->join('jobs', function($join) use ($bindings){
        $join->on('addresses.object_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
             ->where('addresses.object_type', '=', $bindings['job']);
    });

    $addresses = $companies->unionAll($jobs)->get();
```

With the code above I'm getting the following error:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: (select `addresses`.*, `companies`.`company_name` as `object_name` from `addresses` inner join `companies` on `addresses`.`object_id` = `companies`.`id` and `addresses`.`object_type` = 2 where `addresses`.`soft_deleted` = 0) union all (select `addresses`.*, `jobs`.`job_title` as `object_name` from `addresses` inner join `jobs` on `addresses`.`object_id` = `jobs`.`id` and `addresses`.`object_type` = ?))

I've done hours worth of searching but I can't seem to find the answer to this little problem.

Comment: A wild guess: the first `select` alters your `$bindings`. In order to exclude this, I'd dump `$bindings` after each `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it. It was as simple as removing the `->where` from within each join closure and chaining it to the join itself and not nesting it.

Before:

```
$companies = DB::table('addresses')->select(
  'addresses.*',
  'companies.company_name as object_name'
)->where('addresses.soft_deleted', '=', 0)->join('companies', function($join) use ($bindings){
    $join->on('addresses.object_id', '=', 'companies.id')
         ->where('addresses.object_type', '=', $bindings['company']);
});

$jobs = DB::table('addresses')->select(
  'addresses.*',
  'jobs.job_title as object_name'
)->join('jobs', function($join) use ($bindings){
    $join->on('addresses.object_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
         ->where('addresses.object_type', '=', $bindings['job']);
});
```

After:

```
    $companies = DB::table('addresses')->select(
      'addresses.*',
      'companies.company_name as object_name'
    )->where('addresses.soft_deleted', '=', 0)->join('companies', function($join){
        $join->on('addresses.object_id', '=', 'companies.id');
    })->where('addresses.object_type', '=', 2);

    $jobs = DB::table('addresses')->select(
      'addresses.*',
      'jobs.job_title as object_name'
    )->where('addresses.soft_deleted', '=', 0)->join('jobs', function($join){
        $join->on('addresses.object_id', '=', 'jobs.id');
    })->where('addresses.object_type', '=', 4);

    $addresses = $companies->unionAll($jobs)->get();
```

Hope this helps someone.